# How can I open multiple tabs with one anchor tag?

Tags: html, css, web

This is what I have:

```
<a target="_blank" href="projects/code1.cpp">Click to view code.</a>
```

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
<a target="_blank" href="projects/code1.cpp" href="projects/code2.cpp href="projects/header.h">Click to view code.</a>
```

Basically, I am just trying to get it to open multiple tabs with a single anchor tag. What's the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Please update your `Click to view code` :D

Comment: Insert your code in the question itself !

Comment: I just did! :D thanks

Comment: You can do that only with support of JavaScript !

Answer (score 2):

You can javascript in this case

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('http://google.com');
window.open('http://yahoo.com');">Click to open Google and Yahoo</a>
```

Comment: It only opens the first link and the rest of the pop-ups were blocked by Chrome

Comment: You can allow the pop-ups in that case!! It'll work!

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will works

```
<a href="url1" target="_blank" onclick="window.open(url2);  window.open(url3);">Click to view code.</a>
```